# Woocommerce different T&C page for different products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to add different terms and condition pages for different products at woocommerce checkout ?
If a order has some specific product, I need to show different T&C page.

In check out we show T&C page link like image
[image]

From the admin can't do that so I'm going to override the plugin `payment.php` file in my template and do the hack for below part

```
    <?php if ( wc_get_page_id( 'terms' ) > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_show_terms', true ) ) : ?>
                <p class="form-row terms">
//If condition here 
                    <label for="terms" class="checkbox"><?php printf( __( 'I&rsquo;ve read and accept the <a href="%s" target="_blank">terms &amp; conditions</a>', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'terms' ) ) ); ?></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_terms_is_checked_default', isset( $_POST['terms'] ) ), true ); ?> id="terms" />
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Is there any hook for do this in `functions.php` file ?

Comment: But the thing is that if the user buys two different type of product so how you show both term and condition.

Comment: @Noman  That is not going to happen with site setup. User can't buy those two types of products at one cart. Actually we've one special product, so if user going to buy that one. it need to link different T&C

Comment: [**Overriding woocommerce templates via your theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) is as well as a hook. But you have to copy those templates into your theme like explained in the link above, to override them, in the good practices… so after that you can edit **payment.php** template and customize it for your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code in functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_terms_page_permalink', 'replace_permalink');

function replace_permalink($permalink){

// do any change to $permalink here depending on your condition or business case

return $permalink;
}
```

Hope this helps